# How to Access or modify the html code from client template from specific cell of Kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, datagridcell

This is the column bound in kendo grid:

```
columns.Bound(i => i.Article).ClientTemplate(" <div id='aprislst21_#=UppdragUtfortRapporteratID#_#=rownumber#'  onclick=\'aprislst2_RPT(this,#=UppdragUtfortRapporteratID#,
#=KundID#,#=Article_Typ_num#,#=rownumber#,#=UppdragAttesteratID#)\'>  #=UppdragUtfortRapporterat_Benamning# </div>   <input type='text' 
class='cell-hide' id ='aprislst22_#=UppdragUtfortRapporteratID#_#=rownumber#' /> ").Title("Article").Width(250);
```

How do I modify or access this div through edit event? Something like this?

```
function OnEditReportGrid2(e) {
  dataView = this.dataSource.view();
for (var i = 0; i < dataView.length; i++) {
dataView[i].Article.html("????")

// Any thing like this is possible?
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do't modify or access the column just use simple if else condition to display the column inside grid

For Example

```
@{
   var mystring="yes"
 }
```

***************************Grid*************************

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CompanyTypeModel>()

  .Name("FundCompanyTypeGrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
        {

        columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyTypeId).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FundId).Visible(false);
        if(mystring=="yes"){
        columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyIsKycRequired).Title("KYC Required");
        }
        columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyTypeName).Title("Type Name").Width(300);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyTypeDescription).Title("Type Description").Width(520);               
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit();command.Destroy();
          });
        })
```

}

Comment: Hi Shaz , thank you for the reply. I am using the above column for displaying both dropdown and autocomplete. based on the input from other column .i am initaliazing both the dropdown and autocomplete based on the div id in the column. when the user intiates the dropdown and removes the focus from dropdowm somehow i need to restore the div to html code which i had before i intilize the dropdown code. so i need some help to restore the cell when it is out of the focus.... thanks for help in advance....

Comment: you have lost me ..come on the chat room..http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52320/grid-column-autofocus

Comment: Hi, i cant  chat in the room ,as this is my first post in stackoverflow..:(

Comment: i think you can u already have div "id" so jquery $("id").innerHtml() will do the trick for that row column...